# Ubuntu 20.04 - can't see integrated Ryzen GPU

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics, amd-graphics

Just installed fresh Ubuntu 20.04 on my Ryzen 5700G, which has AMD Radeon Vega integrated.
I have installed the AMD driver, from their website.
I'm unable to choose the iGPU in any program. For example Blender shows that there's no compatible device - I've tried Blender 2.83 with OpenCL and Blender 3.4 with HIP - same result.

What do I have to do, to have the GPU visible?

```
apt show amdgpu
Package: amdgpu
Version: 22.20.50200-1438746~20.04
Priority: optional
Section: metapackages
Maintainer: Advanced Micro Devices (AMD) <slava.grigorev@amd.com>
Installed-Size: 9 216 B
Depends: amdgpu-dkms, amdgpu-lib (= 22.20.50200-1438746~20.04)
Download-Size: 1 684 B
APT-Sources: https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/22.20/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
Description: Meta package to install amdgpu components.


dmesg | egrep -i 'radeon|amdgpu'
[    0.507751] smpboot: CPU0: AMD Ryzen 7 5700G with Radeon Graphics (family: 0x19, model: 0x50, stepping: 0x0)
[    3.634251] [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
[    3.642242] amdgpu: Virtual CRAT table created for CPU
[    3.642251] amdgpu: Topology: Add CPU node
[    3.642541] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    3.642632] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: Trusted Memory Zone (TMZ) feature enabled
[    3.649802] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: Fetched VBIOS from ROM BAR
[    3.649805] amdgpu: ATOM BIOS: 13-CEZANNE-019
[    3.650902] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: VRAM: 512M 0x000000F400000000 - 0x000000F41FFFFFFF (512M used)
[    3.650905] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: GART: 1024M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000003FFFFFFF
[    3.650906] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: AGP: 267419648M 0x000000F800000000 - 0x0000FFFFFFFFFFFF
[    3.650964] [drm] amdgpu: 512M of VRAM memory ready
[    3.650965] [drm] amdgpu: 3072M of GTT memory ready.
[    3.651930] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: PSP runtime database doesn't exist
[    3.655578] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: Will use PSP to load VCN firmware
[    4.454533] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: RAS: optional ras ta ucode is not available
[    4.464939] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: RAP: optional rap ta ucode is not available
[    4.464942] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: SECUREDISPLAY: securedisplay ta ucode is not available
[    4.465965] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is initialized successfully!
[    4.501943] snd_hda_intel 0000:05:00.1: bound 0000:05:00.0 (ops amdgpu_dm_audio_component_bind_ops [amdgpu])
[    4.670502] kfd kfd: amdgpu: Allocated 3969056 bytes on gart
[    4.706725] amdgpu: HMM registered 512MB device memory
[    4.706766] amdgpu: SRAT table not found
[    4.706766] amdgpu: Virtual CRAT table created for GPU
[    4.707394] amdgpu: Topology: Add dGPU node [0x1638:0x1002]
[    4.707396] kfd kfd: amdgpu: added device 1002:1638
[    4.707458] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: SE 1, SH per SE 1, CU per SH 8, active_cu_number 8
[    4.710553] fbcon: amdgpudrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    4.826316] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: [drm] fb0: amdgpudrmfb frame buffer device
[    4.865733] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 0
[    4.865737] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.0 uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 0
[    4.865739] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 0
[    4.865741] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.0 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 0
[    4.865742] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.0 uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 0
[    4.865743] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.1 uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 0
[    4.865744] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.1 uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 0
[    4.865745] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.1 uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 0
[    4.865747] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.1 uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 0
[    4.865748] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring kiq_2.1.0 uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 0
[    4.865750] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring sdma0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 1
[    4.865752] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_dec uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 1
[    4.865753] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 1
[    4.865754] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc1 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 1
[    4.865756] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: ring jpeg_dec uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 1
[    4.867982] [drm] Initialized amdgpu 3.42.0 20150101 for 0000:05:00.0 on minor 0



           
inxi -G

Graphics:  Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] driver: amdgpu v: kernel 
Display: server: X.org 1.20.13 driver: amdgpu
resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
OpenGL: renderer: AMD RENOIR (DRM 3.42.0 5.15.0-58-generic LLVM 12.0.0)
v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.6


name of display: :0
display: :0 screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
Vendor: AMD (0x1002)
Device: AMD RENOIR (DRM 3.42.0, 5.15.0-58-generic, LLVM 12.0.0) (0x1638)
Version: 21.2.6
Accelerated: yes
Video memory: 512MB
Unified memory: no
Preferred profile: core (0x1)
Max core profile version: 4.6
Max compat profile version: 4.6
Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
Memory info (GL_ATI_meminfo):
VBO free memory - total: 298 MB, largest block: 298 MB
VBO free aux. memory - total: 3022 MB, largest block: 3022 MB
Texture free memory - total: 298 MB, largest block: 298 MB
Texture free aux. memory - total: 3022 MB, largest block: 3022 MB
Renderbuffer free memory - total: 298 MB, largest block: 298 MB
Renderbuffer free aux. memory - total: 3022 MB, largest block: 3022 MB
Memory info (GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info):
Dedicated video memory: 512 MB
Total available memory: 3584 MB
Currently available dedicated video memory: 298 MB
OpenGL vendor string: AMD
OpenGL renderer string: AMD RENOIR (DRM 3.42.0, 5.15.0-58-generic, LLVM 12.0.0)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

Comment: What does `inxi -G` say? Add the output to your question

Comment: inxi -G
    Graphics:  Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] driver: amdgpu v: kernel 
               Display: server: X.org 1.20.13 driver: amdgpu
resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
OpenGL: renderer: AMD RENOIR (DRM 3.42.0 5.15.0-58-generic LLVM 12.0.0)
v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.6

Comment: No 3D - Renoir LLVM. Try to install the mesa drivers with `sudo apt-get install mesa-va-drivers`

Comment: Mesa is already installed: v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.6

Comment: just to make sure: You don't have an additional external GPU?

Comment: No, this machine has only the integrated GPU.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142230/discussion-between-kanehekili-and-lukas).

Comment: Why is amdgpu driver shown? I have the same on the computer with discrete gpu adaptor.

Comment: @Mahler I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I think Amdgpu driver is related to amd video card.

Comment: @Mahler yes, an as I wrote, I have a Ryzen CPU with integrated AMD Vega 8

Comment: On a Windows Ryzen + integrated Vega 8, in Blender 2.9 I can see the GPU under OpenCL. Same Blender version on a Ryzen PC running Ubuntu shows No compatible devices under OpenCL.